# Encoding $I(X;Y)$ into a random variable $Z$ such that $H(Z) = I(X;Y)$ and $I(X;Z) = I(Y;Z) = I(X,Y)$

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, mutual-information

Is it possible to encode the mutual information $I(X;Y)$ between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ into another random variable $Z$, such that $Z$ "contains" exactly the information that $X$ and $Y$ give about each other, i.e., $H(Z) = I(X;Y)$, $I(X;Z) = I(X;Y)$ and $I(Y;Z) = I(X;Y)$. I suppose one can view this as finding a $Z$ so that $H(Z) = I(X;Y)$ and $X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y$ is a Markov chain. Not sure if that helps.

Put another way, I want a setting in which the Venn diagram imagination is actually precisely correct, i.e. a setting where I can actually point to a random variable $Z$ and say that this $Z$ is exactly the intersection in the Venn diagram.

Here is a simple setting where I can find such a $Z$. Let $Z, a, b$ be indicator random variables such that $a$ and $b$ are independent. Let $X = (Z, a)$ and $Y = (Z, b)$. Then it's intuitively clear that $I(X;Y) = I(X;Z) = I(Y;Z) = H(Z)$. Formally:

$$I(X;Z) = H(Z) - H(Z|X) = H(Z)$$
$$I(Y;Z) = H(Z) - H(Z|Y) = H(Z)$$
$$I(X,Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y) = H(Z,a) - H(a|Z) = H(Z)$$

Can we find such a $Z$ in a more general setting?

Comment: The answer is yes, you can, but then you ask how to find Z in a more general setting? How can you get more general? As far as I can tell, the informal construction you have written here for Z should enable you to model any variables X, Y without restriction. Is your actual question about how specifically to construct appropriate indicators a and b?

Comment: Yes, given X and Y, I want to construct appropriate Z, a, b.

Comment: I don't understand how the construction works for any X and Y. Say X is an
 indicator random variable and Y = X with probability p and Y = not X otherwise. How do I extract a Z from this?

Comment: You mean you actually want to assign real values to Z. That is not possible. Comparing I(X;Y) to H(X), you can see that P_Z(z) must equal P_X,Y(x,y), but it must also equal [P_X,Y(x,y)] / [P_X(x) * P_Y(y)]. This is only possible when P_X(x) * P_Y(y) = 1, which is not always true. Shannon entropy does not permit this construction, but other forms of association can.

Comment: Can you explain why P_Z(z) must equal P_X,Y(x,y)?

Comment: The coefficient to each logarithm term in the sums for for HZ and I(X;Y) must be equal order for HZ and I(X;Y) to be equal for any X, Y (as requested), and for there to be a constructible real valued Z.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135177/discussion-between-superty-and-m-reeves).